# How can I tranform a mesh to make it parallel to a curved one

Tags: modeling

I'm wondering what is the best way to connect these polygons with the curved surface of this sphere (Subsurf applied).
[image]

I tried that but the ngone has sevent vertices. Could it be problematic for after?
[image]

Finally I divide the polygon. So my question is what is the best solution or maybe another better?
[image]

Comment: Does the spherical region really need to be so much denser than the eyelid-like one? You may want to dissolve some edges on the spherical part to get compatible topology.

Comment: I applied a Subsurf modifier to get the sphere smooth (view:3, render:4). These values are too high?

Comment: When you apply a Subsurf Modifier it uses the "View" value, so you used 3. Anyway, it's not that the values are too high (which is relative, varying case by case), it's that they don't match each other. I would probably simplify the geometry of the sphere to match as closely as possible the edge count of the part you want to weld to. *Then* if you need it to be smoother you can put a Subsurf Modifier on the combined mesh.

Comment: Also, it's usually best to model in lower detail because you'll have less verts to manage. Since you can generate further detail using a Subsurf Modifier (never apply it unless you need to - that's a destructive edit) it's usually better to model at lower poly counts.

Comment: One more thing... I see some [non-manifold geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) under the area you welded in your screen shot. You'll want to delete the faces under there after welding because that kind of geometry will mess up your subsurfing, among other problems.

Comment: I don't understand... why never apply a Subsurf unless I need to? The Subsurf modifier adds vertices so that the rendering is smoother. If I model an object at low polygons, for the final result if I want a realistic render I have no other choice than apply a Subsurf modifier?

Comment: @Mentalist, obviously I missed something or my worflow is bad. I mean, if I follow your comment, I should model my object at low polygons, and then add the Subsurf Modifier to have a smooth surface. But how can I turn the polygon surface into a smooth render with a curve hard surface? Even using the Shading smooth option isn't enough to have a surface smooth like glass.

Comment: You don't need to "Apply" the Modifier in order for it to have an effect during rendering. I think that is one of the big points you're missing. Ponder that until you really understand the implications.